# Is it safe to make a network call when a View Controller gets deinited?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, deinit

Basically, I have a UIViewController that controls a chatroom. When the UIViewController gets deinited in any way, then the current user needs to leave the channel.

Currently, my code is:

```
class ChatViewController: SLKTextViewController {

    var channel: TWMChannel? = nil

    // A ton of other code...

    deinit {
        channel!.leaveWithCompletion({
            _ in
        })
    }
```

I've only ever seen code like `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)` in deinit and I haven't found anything online about whether or not this is safe to do.

In essence, this view controller is part of a UINavigationController stack, and whenever the view controller gets popped (which I imagine deinit will always be called during), then I want the user to leave the channel. If there is a preferred way to do this that handles the top left back-button on navigation bars and the panning gesture, then I'd love to see the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in `deinit`, do it in `viewWillDisappear`. That's what you're saying you mean (leave when the user leaves that screen), and more or less that approach sounds fine. However, `channel!.` here is incorrect. You definitely mean `channel?.` so that it does nothing if the channel is not set, rather than crash if the channel is not set.

`deinit` is not promised to be called in the general case, and in any case is only called when the view controller is actually destroyed, which may be much later than you expect (particularly if it's part of a stack).

Comment: Rob, **1)** when is a `viewController` destroyed? **2)** Does that mean when the `viewDidLoad` will get load next time (after destruction)? **3)** In general does viewDidLoad ever get called twice?

Comment: The view controller is destroyed when there are no strong references to it. That depends on many things. You should generally not rely on it for anything. Yes, viewDidLoad would be called again because it would reload the view. You should not rely on viewDidLoad for anything but configuring the view. Never assume a view controller exists when it is offscreen. Never assume a view controller *doesn't* exist anymore when it's offscreen. A view controller exists to manage the view, nothing else.

Comment: The problem with viewWillDisappear is that it is called even when you just press the home button, but I don't want to be leaving and rejoining every time someone opens up the app. I want to leave whenever the view controller is popped. Ideally, I'd want to also leave whenever the app is terminated, but I know that isn't really feasible.

Comment: Take a look at unwind segues. They're the intended tool for managing navigation stack popping.